# How to create a generic XSD type

Tags: java, xsd

I have a java application where i can map a XSD type to another with same type. Now i have requirement to have one anyType xsd to which i can map any type. Like as we have Object type in java, is it possible to create like in XSD.

Edit: At complex type level is it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The type is `xsd:anyType`. Here's an example:

```
<xsd:element name="anything" type="xsd:anyType"/>
```

(Taken from the [primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#anyType))

Here's a more complex example:

```
<xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
      <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="value"    type="xsd:decimal"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

(From the primer as well - it's worth looking at at it)

Comment: Thanks. At complex type level is it possible

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [xs:any](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#any) element - this allows you to have a section of you schema that can contain any arbitrary XML.