# Generics With XML Schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jax-ws, jax-rs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a generic XSD type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130939/how-to-create-a-generic-xsd-type)

Does anyone has a clue how to compose a XSD describing generic java class like:

```
public class PageableResponse<T>
{
    @XmlElement(name = "Data", required = true)
    private List<T> data = new ArrayList<T>();

    public List<T> getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `generateSchema` method on `JAXBContext` to find out the XML schema associated with your class model.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(PageableResponse.class);   
        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName)
                throws IOException {
                return new StreamResult(suggestedFileName);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

**Note:**

A JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will not round trip that particular class.